# Retrieving values from multidimensional JSON object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is probably a really stupid question, but I'm getting a JSON object returned by an API call and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the values out of it.  After I make the call, I pretty print the JSON object and it shows the following:

```
 [
  {
    "link_request": {
      "success": true,
      "link": "https://www.blah.com"
    },
    "errors": null
  }
]
```

I want to be able to get at that link value.  I've tried both of the following, but neither works.

```
var link = data.query.link;

var link = data['query']['link']
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: The root value is an Array. You can access the Object within it using an index -- `data[0]`. And, the other Object within that by one of its properties -- `data[0].link_request`. Etc. ([Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json))

Comment: Also keep in mind, if you are getting a string, parse it into an object via `JSON.parse` and then use access its properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is

```
obj[0].link_request.link
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to get link:

```
jsonArray = [ {
    "link_request": {
      "success": true,
      "link": "https://www.blah.com"
    },
    "errors": null
    }
];
console.log(jsonArray[0].link_request.link)
```